# How can I sum multiple columns in pyspark and return the max?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have a 20 columns like this:

```
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3', ..., 'col20']
```

I am trying to sum all these columns and create a new column where the value of the new column will be 1, if the sum of all the above columns is `>0` and 0 otherwise. I am currently doing it in two steps as shown here:

```
df = df.withColumn("temp_col", col("col1")+col("col2")+...+col("col20"))
df = df.withColumn("new_col_2", when(col("temp_col") > 0, 1).otherwise(0))
```

Is there any way to do this in a one step and also with a better/cleaner way so I don't need to type all these column names?

I was trying to use something like this, but I have got an error.

```
df.na.fill(0).withColumn("new_col" ,reduce(add, [col(col(f'{x}') for x in range(0,20))]))
An error was encountered:
name 'add' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'add' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
cols = ['col' + str(i) for i in range(1, 21)] # ['col1', 'col2',..., 'col20']

df['new_col'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1) > 0
```

If you want 1/0 instead of True/False, you can use `.astype(int)`:

```
df['new_col'] = (df[cols].sum(axis=1) > 0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but got this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sum'.  I am importing sum -> from pyspark.sql.functions import sum

Comment: You do not need to import `sum` as this is part of the `pandas` package. This is the only one you need to import

Comment: @TCMolenaar I think the question is about Spark, not Pandas.`df` is a [Pyspark dataframe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html)

Answer (score 0):

From a Spark point of view everything is ok using the two `withColumn`s. If you are concerned about performance issues due to one extra column let Spark's [Catalyst optimzier](https://www.databricks.com/de/glossary/catalyst-optimizer) deal with this problem.
If you have already a Python array with the columns to be summed up you can create a SQL expression from this array in order to save some typing:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols=df.columns #or cols=[f'col{c}' for c in range(1,21)]
sum_expr="+".join(cols)
df.withColumn("temp_col", F.expr(sum_expr)) \
  .withColumn("new_col_2", F.when(F.col("temp_col") > 0, 1).otherwise(0)) \
  .show()
```

A solution in the direction of your second attempt (but imho overengineered) to calculate the sum would be to use a combination of [array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array.html) and [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html):

```python
df.withColumn("temp_col", F.aggregate(F.array(cols), F.lit(0).cast("long"), lambda l,r: l+r))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cols=['col1','col2','col3', ..., 'col20']
```

Pandas

```
df.assign(x=np.where(df.loc[:, cols].sum(axis=1)>1,1,0))
```

Pyspark

```
new = (df.withColumn('x', array(*[x for x in cols]))#Create array of all columns required
       .withColumn('x', when(expr("reduce(x, cast(0 as double), (c,i)-> c+i)")>0,1).otherwise(0))#combinewhen and reduce
      ).show()
```